# How to install VLC 3.0.20 on 22.04 without snap?

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, multimedia

Is there a way to install the latest VLC 3.0.20 as a native package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Panda Jim's PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntuhandbook1/+archive/ubuntu/vlc):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/vlc
sudo apt install vlc
```

Answer (score 0):

3.0.19 is beta version (as for right now). As a built package it's only available from snapcraft. But if you don't want to use snap you may try building it yourself: https://github.com/videolan/vlc/tree/3.0.x

Comment: No, it's been released https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/tags/3.0.19

Comment: The only built package for 3.0.19 is available on snap and is marked as beta https://snapcraft.io/vlc

https://artifacts.videolan.org/vlc-3.0/nightly-snap/20231010-0225/

And yep, https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc seems to be fresher